# Calculate integral when I have a pole on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm having trouble integrating the following integral

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{3 -2\cos\theta + \sin\theta}$$

I make the substitutions $z= e^{i\theta}$ , $\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2i}(z-\frac{1}{z})$ and $\cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$, and then calculate the roots of the denominator.

I calculate the two roots to be

$z_+ = \frac{2-i}{5}$

$z_- = 2-i$

The problem is that $z_+$ lies on the unit circle itself, and therefore I can't apply Residue theorem.
I think I somehow have to calculate the Principal value, but I'm not sure how?

Comment: You have miscalculated, the denominator $3-2\cos\theta + \sin\theta$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore the substitution $z = e^{i\theta}$ cannot lead to something having a pole on the unit circle.

Comment: I've double checked my calculation of the poles on Mathematica. This would mean I've done something wrong in my substitution, the poles were calculated from this equation $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{iz(3-z-\frac{1}{z} + \frac{z}{2i} - \frac{1}{2iz})}$

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes to calculate myself.

Comment: **D'oh!** $$\left\lvert \frac{2-i}{5}\right\rvert^2 = \frac{2^2 + 1^2}{5^2} = \frac{5}{25} = \frac{1}{5} \neq 1.$$ Should have seen that immediately.

Comment: Facepalm! Thank you :D